# How to use facebook token from cookie?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies

I can get facebook access token on client side of asp.net mvc application with method **FB.getLoginStatus()**

The token:

EAAFjVDcBGp4BABSnPzvjeR0ZCqEHExSRIGtvEIMPZCZABh****fk03WZCg10xaPJUs3ZCZAMTnP8

It's set token to cookies. I want to access it on server side, but on server I get it:

Kk9fbM-3d8ih4SpCfMddsj23BW2bqwPlll9LLs8ZYUE.eyJh****IjEwNzI4NDM4NjQ0OTI5MiJ9

Why? What should I do to get token from cookie?

**UPDATED**

Client code:

```
function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') 
            return;
        FB.login();
    });
}
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppParameterKey.FbApplicationId],
        cookie     : true, 
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.8' 
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Server code:

```
var userToken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[String.Concat("fbsr_", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppParameterKey.FbApplicationId])].Value
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Please see updated post

Answer (score 0):

The cookies doesn't contains access_token

After a day I founded solution here:

[Problem getting access_token after migrating to OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201521/problem-getting-access-token-after-migrating-to-oauth-2-0)